# Reinforcement learning with 0 rewards and costs

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent

Suppose we have a hallway environment, i.e, $N$ nodes from left to right, and we can either move left or right. Moving left at the leftmost node does nothing and reaching the right most node gives you a $+1$ reward and terminates the game. But every other action has $0$ cost or reward.

I'm curious to know how reinforcement learning works in this case, because based on what I know it shouldn't.

Consider a trajectory $\tau = (o_0, a_0, \cdots o_H, a_H)$ sequence of observations and actions up till horizon $H$. Then the gradient by the gradient policy theorem looks like $g = \sum_{h = 1}^H [\sum_{t = h}^H\text{Reward at step t}]g_\pi(a_h|\tau_h)$ where $g_\pi(a_h|\tau_h)$ is the gradient of the log probability of choosing action $a_h$ given the trajectory up till step $h$, $\tau_h$.

But if Reward = 0 at every step, and we only get a reward of $1$ at termination, doesn't this simply become: $\sum_{h = 1}^H1\cdot g_\pi(a_h|\tau_h)$? And this is a bad thing since when we do gradient update to the params this weighs us towards the action of moving left as well, and obviously we want our policy to tell us to go right. So it seems the gradient signals the wrong directions to move in (in policy space).

So how would the typical policy gradient update technique work here? Am I wrong or does it not work?

More questions: How is this affected by $N$ the number of nodes? My intuition is that it shouldn't be (after all, $N$ doesn't even appear in the equation above). But I'm not sure.

Comment: If you don't get any reinforcement from the environment, learning becomes difficult.

Comment: Are you assuming that every trajectory $\tau$ will hit the rightmost node and give you $+1$ reward?  That assumption does not look valid.